# Payment Request API - unable to add a fake or real credit card

Tags: google-chrome

I've worked on this Google Payment Request API Codelab and while the app, code, ui and most of the payment flows work as expected, I am unable to add a payment credit card - I also checked a few other demo sites and I am simply stuck on the add card browser UI and clicking the "Add" button simply does not add the card and return to the overview screen.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/payment-request-api/

I am using the Chrome Browser on the Desktop, not via mobile as in the codelab, but this should still work on Chrome 76...

Any ideas? Also, I was exposing the test app via a https:// endpoint and tested it from there.

Comment: This subject matter isn't really on-topic on SU.  I'm guessing it might be on-topic at SO.  However, I'm pretty sure they will require more detail, like your code if it's a coding problem.  If it's an issue with using tools provided by the publisher of a web app, I'm not sure where it would be on-topic, but that might not fall under the Web Apps site.  I voted to close rather than try to migrate this, because it isn't clear what the right site would be, or whether this would meet the requirements of another site as-is.  (cont'd)

Comment: You might want to try getting feedback from site mods or on the Meta sites, probably starting with SO, on whether this would be on-topic and what additional detail might be needed.  Good luck with your project.